# Method Overriding in Objective-C

Tags: java, objective-c, inheritance

I am a java programmer who has started to make apps for iPhone. I have stumbled with a problem. Supose the following code (in java):

**Class 1** (building)

```
public abstract class Building
{
    public void Update()
    {
        specialAction();
    }

    public abstract void specialAction();
}
```

**Class 2** (House)

```
public abstract class House extends Building
{   
    public abstract void specialAction()
    {
        System.out.println("Special Action Done");
    }
}
```

**Runnable Class**

```
public class Program
{   
    public void main(String[] args)
    {
        House h = new House();
        h.Update();
    }
}
```

When the `Update` method from `House h` (running from the superclass Building) is called in `Program` the method `specialAction` from `House` is called and thus the Console prints "Special Action Done". My question is, would the following code in xcode be equivalent (in terms of inheritance and method overriding rather that console output):

**Class 1** (building):
.h file:

```
-(void)Update;
-(void)SpecialAction;
```

.m file:

```
-(void)Update
{
    [self specialAction];
}
```

**Class 2** (House, which extends or inherits from `Building`):
.m file:

```
-(void)SpecialAction
{
    NSLog("Special Action Done");
}
```

**Runnable Class**

```
House* h = [[House alloc] init];
[h Update];
```

Comment: What did happen, when you tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example looks correct. A full program of your Java example is approximated in ObjC like so:

```
/* Building.h */
@interface Building : NSObject
- (void)Update;
- (void)specialAction;
@end

/* Building.m */
@implementation Building

- (void)Update
{
    [self specialAction];
}

- (void)specialAction
{
    assert(0 && "override required"); // << see note
}

@end

/* House.h */
@interface House : Building
@end

/* House.m */
@implementation House

- (void)specialAction
{
    NSLog(@"Special Action Done");
}

@end

void ProgramMain()
{
    House * h = [House new];
    [h Update];
    [h release];
}
```

Formal abstract methods are not built into the language, but you can approximate it using protocols.

You can consider all ObjC methods to be virtual.

Comment: The "standard" way of creating methods in an abstract class is sending a `doesNotRecognizeSelector` message, i.e. `[self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];`

Comment: @sebnow I don't consider either "standard". It was really just an illustration. An implementation may take multiple forms.

Answer (score 2):

Does `House` inherit from `Building`?

```
@interface House : Building
```

If so, you don't have to implement your special action here with a different name.
You can declare

```
-(void)Update;
```

in House.h

and define it in House.m as

```
-(void)Update
{
    NSLog("Special Action Done");
}
```

and calling the `Update` method on a `House` object will invoke the definition in House.m

P.S. Since you are new to iOS, I'd like to mention the convention that: class names such as "House" start with a capital letter; method names and variable names start with lowercase letters.

Comment: Sorry for not explaning but on both the java and Objective-C examples the class <code>House</code> extends <code>Building</code>